# Consultation about send control spinner to my method

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have in my Android program 5 Spinner

I also have method that I need to sent status and the Spinner

for example: the Method

```
public void Fix_Combo1(String N,[sppiner SP - ???])
{
    switch (N)
    {
        case "AA":
             SP.setSelection(0);
            break;
        case "BB":
            SP.setSelection(1);
            break;
        case "CC":
            SP.setSelection(2);
            break;
        default:
            SP.setSelection(0);
    }
}
```

for example: the sending

```
Fix_Combo1(R1,Spiner SP ?);
```

how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly : you can't use `String` in `switch` statement.

> `switch` statement on String objects is a new feature introduced in `Java 1.7` . Unfortunately most of Android sdks requires version `1.6` or `1.5`. This is why you have to forget for some time about such constructions.

secondly : If you want to send one of your `Spinner` to method just send the `Spinner` object :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    Spinner sp1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp1);
    Spinner sp2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp1);
    Spinner sp3=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp1);
    Spinner sp4=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp1);

    //Send by name
    Fix_Combo1(2,  sp1);

    // OR Send by Number
    ArrayList<Spinner> sp_list=new ArrayList<Spinner>();
    sp_list.add(sp1);
    sp_list.add(sp2);
    sp_list.add(sp3);
    sp_list.add(sp4);

    Fix_Combo1(2,  sp_list.get(2));


}

private void Fix_Combo1(int N, Spinner SP ) {


    switch (N)
    {
        case 1:
            SP.setSelection(0);
            break;
        case 2:
            SP.setSelection(1);
            break;
        case 3:
            SP.setSelection(2);
            break;
        default:
            SP.setSelection(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you got your source, but the latest Android API versions support Java 7. The newest, even Java 8

Comment: Android API supports this of course but think of older android devices which run an older java version